# como deixar apenas o input de um dialog com o draggable desabilitado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tenho uma função que faz o dialogo ficar com o draggable habilitado mas preciso conseguir editar um input dentro desse dialog. Como faço para apenas esse input não estar herdando o draggable do pai dialog?

função para deixar draggable habilitado:

```
function addDraggable(identifier, cancel) { 
 $('.'+identifier).parent().draggable({
        cancel: cancel + ", :button"
    });
 focusInputText();
```

}

função que fiz pra conseguir editar o input, até funciona, mas não consigo navegar pelo corretamente pelo input:

```
function focusInputText() { 
    $( 'input[type=text].urlCam' ).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $( this ).focus();
    });
}
```

Comment: Draggable do jQuery UI?

Comment: @LIN isso mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só adicionar algum seletor para este *input* na propriedade `cancel`.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$('#drag').draggable({
    cancel: '.dont-drag'
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="drag" style="background-color: #CCC">

<input class="dont-drag" type="text">
<input type="text">
<button class="dont-drag">Botão 1</button>
<button>Botão 2</button>

</div>
```